# finding a function with natual coefficient from a set of real roots

Tags: calculus

If I give a set of real numbers such as r1, r2 ...
then is it possible to find out one or more function(s) (no matter if it is poly- or no polynomial) which the roots of those functions are r1, r2 ..., while all numbers, powers, or coefficients exist in the function are natural numbers (\in N)?

Comment: There would exist sets of real numbers for which it is impossible - for example include [Champernowne's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) in the set and it should be impossible. However I don't have a proof of this so I'll glad stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Let's fix a (countable) description language for functions.

Almost all real numbers are trascendental number with infinite [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), i.e. the total amount of information that is necessary to describe the number (in the fixed description language) is infinite. For a number $\alpha$ of this kind you should have this: if $f$ is such that $\alpha$ is the $n$th root of $f$ then $f$ can't be described (using the fixed description language) with a finite algorithm/description.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I can not insert a comment. I do not understand what you mean bu saying "function with natural coefficients not polynomial"; for sure, for numbers as $\pi$ there is no chance to have a such a polynomial expression (do you allow power series?). For the same number, you can write this function (if for root of the function you mean a zero) $x\mapsto 1+\cos(x)$ which is zero for $x=\pi$, but is this kind of functions the one you are searching for?